# Can I stop "Filter says params are" line from being printed to stdout?

Tags: grails

A 2.1.1 Grails app has a filter, and in development mode lines like this get printed on every request:

```
Filter says params are: [controller:book, action:list]
```

How can I stop this? (I don't think it is anything in my code doing it)

Comment: Are you sure this is not from you own code?

Comment: it should be something in your filters user defined code :)

Comment: Love those down votes with no explanation why I got down voted... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [functional test plugin](https://github.com/Grailsrocks/grails-functional-test)? A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Filter%20says%20params%20are%22) returned the suspect println you're seeing in the functional test plugin's [grails-app/conf/TestFilters.groovy](https://github.com/Grailsrocks/grails-functional-test/pull/4/files) filter. If you are using the plugin, it looks like it's been removed/commited in Mar 2012, so you may need an update.

Otherwise if you're not using the functional test plugin, I would inspect your grails-app/conf/ directory for any *Filters.groovy and it's contents.

Comment: It was the functional test plugin. Thanks! (it was driving me nuts).